# CSS Disabled on My SP online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, custom-masterpage

**Scenario**: I have created a custom master page for our site, all the custom JS and CSS is been on master page folder

**Error**: one of sudden day All the CSS are disabled automatically, I have checked with the network there are not any blockage from the firewall

**Temporary Solution:** Temporary solution I found that when I check out the page it works fine but after publish it ruins

Looking for expert advice on that

**[image: Tried Solution]** **Tried Solution**: I tried to publishing feature ON/OFF but not works in my case

even Default master page (seattle and oslo ) have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to SharePoint Admin Center, and make sure "Custom Script" setting is enabled. If not, enable it. After change, it might take up to 24 hours to take effect.

Try to re-add the these disabled references using SharePoint Designer 2013.

If this issue still exists, you may need to contact Office 365 support to check if some backend changes/updates caused this issue via Admin Center->Support->new service request.